# How do I resolve this error while setting up numpy?

Tags: python, windows, numpy, pip

I used the command "pip install numpy" but I'm getting the following error.
I am using Python 3.9.0, pip 20.2.4

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\users\abc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\abc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpheac_o64'

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\abc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\abc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpheac_o64' Check the logs for full command output.
```

How do I resolve this?

Edit : pip3 doesn't work either.

Comment: try: pip3 install numpy

Comment: @BIGPESH same result with pip3 as well

Comment: @CForce99 yes it does. Thanks a lot!